# Python: Ошибка при запросе данных о погоде 'OWM' object has no attribute 'coindex_around_coords'

Tags: python, pyowm

Начал изучать программирование, язык: Python.
Учусь и пытаюсь создать телеграмм бота, который бы возвращал данные о погоде в указанном пользователем городе.
Использую библиотеку `PyOWM v3` для определения погоды.

В целом телеграмм бот работает и возвращает основные данные, но с некоторыми данными например, уровень углекислого газа CO index запрос написать не выходит, при запуске кода ошибка: `OWM' object has no attribute 'coindex_around_coords'`

Воспроизвел здесь часть кода для разбора проблемы.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config


city = input("готод:")

owm = OWM ('API_key')
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "name_of_your_app")

location = geolocator.geocode(city)

lat = location.latitude
lon=location.longitude
print(lat, lon)

coi = owm.coindex_around_coords(lat, lon)

print(coi)
```

Т.е ошибка в том что `owm` не содержит объект `coindex_around_coords`,
но при этом в документации: https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v3/air-pollution-api-usage-examples.html приведен такой именно пример реализации.

Или быть может нужно вызывать `CO index api` запросом параметра `get_coi`? Не могу сообразить.

Comment: примите ответ, чтобы другие могли понимать, что он вам помог

Answer (score 0):

У них много устаревших примеров - документация похоже заброшена. Сейчас вам нужен отдельный менеджер на каждый API похоже:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config


city = input("город:")

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
owm = OWM('API_key', config_dict)

mgr = owm.weather_manager()

# Создаем менеджер для AirPollution   
air = owm.airpollution_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent = "name_of_your_app")

location = geolocator.geocode(city)

lat = location.latitude
lon = location.longitude
print(lat, lon)

# И используем уже его метод
coi = air.coindex_around_coords(lat, lon)

print(coi)
```